# i18n in DataFX, JavaFX application getting LoadException: No resources specified

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am new to DataFX (and using DataFx8) and struggling to get localisation working. My main class is as shown:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        //set language
        ViewConfiguration viewConfig = new ViewConfiguration();
        Locale locale = new Locale("en","EN");
        viewConfig.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle(UIConstants.LANGUAGE_BUNDLE_PREFIX, locale));

        Flow applicationRootFlow = new Flow(HomeController.class, viewConfig);
        FlowHandler applicationRootFlowHandler = applicationRootFlow.createHandler();

        StackPane root = applicationRootFlowHandler.start(new DefaultFlowContainer());
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, UIConstants.APPLICATION_WIDTH, UIConstants.APPLICATION_HEIGHT));
        primaryStage.setTitle(UIConstants.APPLICATION_TITLE);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I have traced the code through, and the debug shows the Flow has loaded the resource successfully (see attached image).
[image]

The resource has the required index, but the fxml is not loading the string, instead crashing with 
Caused by:... javafx.fxml.LoadException: No resources specified. /C:/.../Home.fxml:22

The line in the fxml is:

```
<Label fx:id="languageLabel" text="%displayLanguage" />
```

The resource bundle is:

```
applicationTitle=Service222222
displayLanguage=English
```

So is there something I am missing? Can I no longer do translation straight from fxml file due to different loading model of datafx (controller specifies fxml file)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For others who come across this:
This is due to a bug when calling `createHandler()` method on the Flow. The current DataFx implementation ignores the `ViewConfiguration` object that is associated with the Flow and will always create new configurations (resources is always null) when returning the `FlowHandler` object.

As a workaround, avoid calling `createHandler(`) to get the `FlowHandler` object. Instead, create it manually by calling the `FlowHandler` constructor that takes in the view configurations as a parameter.

`applicationRootFlowHandler = new FlowHandler(applicationRootFlow, new ViewFlowContext(), viewConfig);`